# Why doesn't `https://tls-v1-0.badssl.com:1010/` open in Internet Explorer 6, when Internet Explorer 6 supposedly supports TLS 1.0?

Tags: internet, windows, security, web-browser

Internet Explorer 6 supports TLS 1.0. However, for some reason that escapes me, https://tls-v1-0.badssl.com:1010/ (which is supposed to test whether a browser supports TLS v1.0) fails to open in Internet Explorer 6. And it fails to open not with "Cannot establish a secure connection.", but with "Cannot find server or DNS error.". Firefox 52 in that same virtual machine can open that web-page. What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's because that version of Internet Explorer does not support [Server Name Indication](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-server-name-indication#:%7E:text=Server%20Name%20Indication%20(SNI)%20allows,in%20the%20CLIENT%20HELLO%20message.), which is part of the TLS protocol which allows a secure handshake to be established when multiple domains with different certificates are hosted at the same IP. If badssl.com is hosted on shared hosting, then I think this explains your issue.

On [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69710/which-browsers-support-sni), the following list of browsers supporting SNI is given: (accurate to November 2014)

Please also read [this other question on Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61637/does-an-ssl-certificate-actually-require-a-dedicated-ip?rq=1) for more information about secure connections on shared and unique IPs.

> **Internet Explorer 7 or newer, on Windows Vista or newer.**
>
> Mozilla Firefox 2.0 or later
>
> Opera 8.0 or newer (TLS 1.1 protocol needs to be enabled)
>
> Opera Mobile with at least version 10.1 bèta on Android
>
> Google Chrome (Vista or newer. XP on Chrome 6 or newer)
>
> OS X 10.5.7 or newer on Chrome 5.0.342.1 or newer
>
> Safari 2.1 or later (Mac OS X 10.5.6 or newer and Windows Vista or newer)
>
> Konqueror/KDE 4.7 or newer
>
> MobileSafari in Apple iOS 4.0 or newer
>
> Android default browser on Honeycomb or newer
>
> Windows Phone 7
>
> MicroB on Maemo

> The following browsers do not support SNI:
>
> **Internet Explorer, all versions, Windows XP**
>
> Safari, Windows XP
>
> BlackBerry Browser
>
> Windows Mobile 6.5 and lower
>
> Android 2.x default browser

Comment: Interesting, that was my hunch when I saw the question...

Comment: Then why exactly does Internet Explorer complain that there was a DNS error?

Comment: @FlatAssembler The the error message doesn't say that. It says "*Cannot find server* or DNS error." The first part is correct so far as it goes, because connecting to the server needs some functionality that the software doesn't know about. You can't produce a *good* error message about something that doesn't even exist in your software.

Comment: @FlatAssembler: From what I (mis?)remember, IE used to show the rather generic "Cannot find server" even in situations where it _could_ have shown a better one, e.g. if the server was simply down, or if it returned certain HTTP error codes. It just wasn't very good at error messages in general.

Comment: @user1686: Maybe badssl requires SNI outright rather than giving you the decoder page and you get cannot find server for the protocol mismatch.